# Same convention working for all other instances but this one

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, split

I have a call to a database where it gets a pipe delimited string which i break into an array and fill text boxes, this exact code works for every other instance except this one, and i can figure out why. this instances only prints the first two letters of the string into the two textboxes

the data that would come from the query looks like this "this is a test|this is a test"

```
    Dim queryString3 As String = "SELECT Answer FROM ShortAnswers where questionNumber = 12 and submission = 1375"
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString3, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim rdr As String = command.ExecuteScalar()
        Dim P3 As String
        P3 = rdr
        Dim Part3 As New ArrayList(P3.Split("|"c))
        TextBoxA.Text = Part3(0)
        TextBoxB.Text = Part3(1)
```

in this example textboxa takes the value of "t"
and textbox b takes the value of "h"
the first two letters from "this is a test|this is a test"

this nearly identical piece works

```
    Dim queryString As String ="SELECT Answer FROM ShortAnswers where questionNumber = 11 and submission = 1375"          
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.OnLineTestingDB)
        Dim command2 As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim rdr1 As String = command2.ExecuteScalar()
        Dim P2 As String
        P2 = rdr1
        Dim Part2 As New ArrayList(P2.Split("|"c))
        Normal.Text = Part2(0)
        Normal1.Text = Part2(1)
        Normal2.Text = Part2(2)
    End Using
```

Comment: Please post **actual** values for `SubmissionID`, results of the query, the value of P3 when it doesn't work, and more details on how it "doesn't work".  Note, also, this code is ripe for a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: the app is only running locally, the submissionID is not the issue the query works fine, as i stated in the question the results of the query look something like "foo bar|foo bar"

Comment: I read the question and saw that results look *something like* xyz. But you've got a bugaboo that's stumping you; the more *precise* the details you provide the better the community can help.  Maybe the community will see something in the query you aren't seeing, or maybe it's not the query -- but right now we can only guess.

Comment: okay, i'm trying to think if theres more useful parts of my code to put in there, could it have to do with the fact its a two array?

Comment: Do the text boxes have a max length of 2, by any chance?

Comment: theyre all formatted like this <asp:TextBox id="Normal"     runat="server" /></td>

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that is was taking the charatcters from the string not the array

```
Dim Part3 As New ArrayList(P3.Split("|"c))
   TextBoxA.Text = P3(0)
   TextBoxB.Text = P3(1)
```

it now looks like

```
Dim Part3 As New ArrayList(P3.Split("|"c))
   TextBoxA.Text = Part3(0)
   TextBoxB.Text = Part3(1)
```

which corrected the issue, thank you for your help, sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes to wake you up

Comment: The code you originally posted did not show that.  That's why it's important to post _actual_ code by copy and pasting rather than typing it in from memory.